# Create a reference inside a class to his own type

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I really didn't know how to write the title for this problem :P

So in google app engine I want to create a class that can have 'sons' of the same type:

```
class Chapter(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    note = db.TextProperty()
    father = db.ReferenceProperty(Chapter, collection_name='sons')
    order = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

and I get the error

```
NameError: name 'Chapter' is not defined
```

Is it possible to create this? Or is this a really stupid idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [SelfReferenceProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#SelfReferenceProperty)

```
class Chapter(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    note = db.TextProperty()
    father = db.SelfReferenceProperty(collection_name='sons')
    order = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```